# Convert Excel zip file content to actual Excel file?

Tags: python, cmis

I am using `cmis` package available in python to download the document from FileNet repository. I am using getcontentstream method available in the package. However it returns content file that beings with 'Pk' and ends in 'PK'. when I googled I came to know it is excel zip package content. is there a way to save the content into an excel file. I should be able to open the downloaded excel. I am using below code. but getting byte-liked object is required not str. I noticed type of result is `string.io`.

```
# expport the result
result = testDoc.getContentStream()
outfile = open(sample.xlsx, 'wb')
outfile.write(result.read())
result.close()
outfile.close()
```

Comment: Maybe `.encode("latin-1")` the output to get a bytes object?

Comment: use the `zipfile` package to unzip the file/stream -> https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipfile.html

Comment: Python doesn't come with a module in its standard library to read and write Excel `.xlsx` format files, so you will probably need to find and install one from a third party to so (or write your own code to do it).

Comment: @Wouterr. Thank you for your response. It worked. I encode with latin-1 and it converted string into bytes and i am successfully able to open the excel file without any issues.  My code working code below. 
result = testDoc.getContentStream()
outfile = open(sample.xlsx, 'wb')
outfile.write(result.read().encode('latin-1'))
result.close() 
outfile.close()

Comment: @Bitonator. Thanks for taking a look at my question and for your reply. Appreciate it

Comment: @martineau.Thanks for taking a look at my question and for your reply. Appreciate it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi there and welcome to stackoverflow. There are a few bits I noticed about your post.

To answer the error code you are getting directly. You called the outfile FileStream to be in terms of binary, however the result.read() must be in Unicode string format which is why you are getting this error. You can try to encode it before passing it to the outfile.write() function (ex: `outfile.write(result.read().encode())`).

You can also simply just write Unicode directly by:

```
result = testDoc.getContentStream()
result_text = result.read()

from zipfile import ZipFile

with ZipFile(filepath, 'w') as zf:
    zf.writestr('filename_that_is_zipped', result_text)
```

Not I am not sure what you have in your ContentStream but note that a excel file is made up of xml files zipped up. The minimum file structure you need for an excel file is as follows:

- `_rels/.rels` contains excel schemas
- `docProps/app.xml` contains number of sheets and sheet names
- `docProps/core.xml` boiler plate user info and date created
- `xl/workbook.xml` contains sheet names rdId to workbook link
- `xl/worksheets/sheet1.xml` (and more sheets in this folder) contains cell data for each sheet
- `xl/_rels/workbook.xml.rels` contains sheet file locations within zipfile
- `xl/sharedStrings.xml` if you have string only cell values
- `[Content_Types].xml`applies schemas to file types

I recently went through piecing together an excel file from scratch, if you want to see the code check out https://github.com/PydPiper/pylightxl

Comment: Thank you for your response. It worked. I encode with latin-1 and it converted string into bytes and i am successfully able to open the excel file without any issues. My code working code below. result = testDoc.getContentStream() outfile = open(sample.xlsx, 'wb') outfile.write(result.read().encode('latin-1')) result.close() outfile.close()